# Unknown Type name "Firebase"

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am new to IOS developing and I am creating a IOS app with FirebaseUI. I followed the http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/FirebaseUI/0.3.2/ document and I get the following error when I added the Firebase reference,[image]

This is in TableViewController.h file

Comment: @EI Captain v2.0  Isn't this for Firebase? I am using FirebaseUI What about FirebaseTableViewDataSource *dataSource;

Comment: Read the error message: you need to use object type: Firebase and FirebaseTableViewDataSource is not the object type.

Comment: you have to declare @class Firebase in your TableViewController.h .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import proper module for FirebaseUI please import below module for TableView Class.

```
@import FirebaseDatabaseUI;
```

It will help you to get all **UI** related classes into your app.

Comment: Can you update the answer for latest crashlytics, i got the same error. But you answer not helps.

Answer (score 0):

After searching alot I have found that most of the libraries have deprecated and need to add `#import <FirebaseDatabaseUI/FirebaseTableViewDataSource.h>` to resolve the error

Comment: You have to import whole module of `FireBaseDatabaseUI` so it will automatically import all intermediate classes so no need to import single file like above. Check my answer for the same.